# FirebaseMessagingService ghost notification?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a firebase services extended from FirebaseMessagingService

Here definition of method

```
@Override
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
  Log.e(Tag_App, "From data: ${remoteMessage?.from}")
}
```

So.
On foreground( app on screen).. it work.. writte log.

but on background (closed app)..notification appear on notification bar on phone but as you can see there is not code for generate notification( i had written that before but i delete it)...

Y try new with new adv but the same result..notification appear when app is on background.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you are receiving ["Notification" type messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages). More information can be found here. In summary:

> ***When your app is in Foreground***
>
> - Developer needs to handle the notification message in the handler.
> - Post a notification or update app content in the FCM callback.
>
> ***When your app is in Background***
>
> - Notification delivered to System Tray.

Comment: So.. it mean that..when is in background the notification, is out of control of my services?..

Comment: Correct, if it's of type "Notification". If that's not what you want, you could instead send messages of type "Data", in which case your service will always receive the message regardless of whether your app is in the foreground or background.